# A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ShoppingWAR/shooperServlet has not been defined

Tags: websphere

I am trying to add one web application in to the existing EAR. I have added the web.xml and a servlet file and packaged it as a war then packaged it in the EAR. When i am trying to access the servlet in internet explorer i am getting the page can not be displayed error. I am not sure whats is going wrong here.

I am getting the following error in system.out log

> A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ShoppingWAR/shooperServlet has not been defined.
>   Any help in this is highly appreciated. I am ready to give further file details if you need friends.

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    
                
                DataBase
                jdbc.shoppingmall
                javax.sql.DataSource
                Container
                Shareable
            
    
      shooperServlet 
      shooperServlet

```
  <servlet-class>com.shopping.shooperServlet </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

shooperServlet 
            /shooperServlet

Answer (score 1):

Besides what chro has mentioned ensure that the web app is deployed to the correct virtual host. By default there are two virtual hosts (one for applications and one for the admin console). I don't know if you have added additional VHosts.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: I deployed it in default host only

Comment: Karthick, VH error simply states that you are trying to access the web component via a URL which is not in synch with what is deployed to the VH. The default VH is for port 9080. So if you are accessing the URL as: http://localhost:9080/ShoppingWAR/shooperServlet then it would work (assuming your app is running). What is the URL that you are accessing. Notice that the defautl host supports only port 80 and 9080. Any other port specified in the URL will fail with this error.

Comment: i am also getting this error in the log Web Module <null> has been bound to default_host[*:80,*:9080,*:9081,*:9443,*:9444,*:443,*:9086,*:9449,*:9083,*:9446,*:9087,*:9450,*:9448,*:9085,*:9088,*:9089].

Comment: Karthick, When a module is deployed it will clearly state that it is bound to a specific host. In this case, ShoppingWAR would be bound to default_host which is 9080. Also is there a typo in shooperServlet. Should that be shopperServlet? What is the mapping in web.xml. I am also assuming your context root is indeed "ShoppingWAR".

Comment: Hi manglu yes there is a typing mistake but i have used the same word across all my files so i find no issue with that. i have placed my web.xml in the end of my post itself.Can you please check and yes my context root is /ShoppingWAR

Comment: Karthick, What is important is the servlet mapping as that translates to the URL/URI. You haven't stated that in your web.xml post. Is there any JSP that you have in the web app. Are you able to access that?

Comment: hi i have given my web.xml in the above original post it self and the good news is i have solved the issue . i missed the <archive>
 <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
 <manifest>
  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
 </manifest>
</archive> which caused this issue now its working fine  thanks for ur time and help :)

Comment: Karthick, Adding a maven descriptor is not the solution to your problem. VH is a configuration on WAS and there is nothing in your maven build that is going to solve this for you. It simply boils down to deploying an application to a virtual host (which represents the host and port number). You web.xml does not show the servlet mapping tag (which is what i was after). This is what is used by the App Server to route request(s).